# Latex tikz left-align text on path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want the text to align to the left on the line like in the second picture below.
Are there better ways to do replicate the second images template?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\draw (0.1,3.5)-- node[anchor=south ]{$B(y)$}(2.9,3.5); %align = left in node option doesnt work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: My result]

[image: What I try to achieve]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This is not the best solution, but works.... `\draw (0.1,3.5)node[anchor=south west]{$B(y)$} -- (2.9,3.5);`

Comment: I have tried the west option too, but it does not align smoothly to the very beginning.

Comment: It is because the sep. Use `\draw (0.1,3.5)node[anchor=south west,inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt]{$B(y)$} -- (2.9,3.5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, but depending on what you wish, the code could be more flexible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\draw (0.1,3.5)node[anchor=south west,inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt]{$B(y)$} -- (2.9,3.5); %align = left in node option doesnt work
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum width=3cm, minimum height=4cm,draw] (box) at (0,0){};

\node[anchor=north west, text width=3cm - 4pt, align=left, inner xsep=2pt] (head) at (box.north west){$B(y)$};

\draw ([xshift=2pt]head.south west) -- ([xshift=-2pt]head.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there much one can do to make it more reuseable? My professor used this template like 100 times over the entire document, and I think it would be hard to maintain such a document.

Comment: Well, I'm almost sure that he is not using TikZ. You can produce boxes with text inside it. The figure looks like a framed box algorithm. Search for it here.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/849776666161971240/908376231723008060/unknown.png here is a little collection of graphs he make. Do you think he used something different than TikZ?

Comment: It is possible to produce 4 tikz pictures like that all together.